# Case When, on Else get value from existing column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with this structure :

[image: df]

I want:
`IF Year >= 2010 then 2010 ELSE Year` (take the original value when under 2010).

With this code it works for the values from 2010 and up, but it only inserts 2003 (the first row) from the original values.

```
def case_when(row):
    if (row['Year'] >= 2010) : return 2010 
    else:
        return df_year['Year']

df_year['Year'] = df_year.apply(case_when, axis=1)
```

Comment: [Please dont post images of data/code when asking a question in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: why not use `MIN(year, 2010)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use apply when a vectorized way is possible with `np.where` from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
...
df_year['Year'] = np.where(df_year['Year'] >= 2010, 2010, df_year['Year'])
```

Comment: Thank you, even if I tried something similar as well that did not work, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

`df['Year'] = [min(x, 2010) for x in df['Year']]`